# Bouncing Ball. Making it slow down at peak of height

Tags: graphics, 3d, x3d, x3dom

I have created a bouncing ball animation in x3d. I am just curious how I could make the ball slow down at the peak of its height to make it look more realistic. Thank you in advance.

```
<X3D profile="interactive">
    <Scene>
        <Background skyColor='0.5 0.5 1'/>

    <Transform DEF="Ball" translation="0 1 0" >
    <TouchSensor DEF="Touch"/>
            <Shape>
                <Appearance>
                    <Material diffuseColor="1 0 0 "/>
                </Appearance>
                <Sphere radius='1'/>
            </Shape>
        </Transform>

    <TimeTrigger DEF="Trigger"/>
        <TimeSensor DEF="Clock" loop="false" cycleInterval="5" />    
        <PositionInterpolator DEF="Position" key="0.0 0.5 1.0" keyValue="0 1 0 0 5 0 0 1 0"/>

        <ROUTE fromNode="Clock" fromField="fraction_changed" toNode="Position" toField="set_fraction"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="Position" fromField="value_changed" toNode="Ball" toField="set_translation"/>
    <ROUTE fromNode="Touch" fromField="isActive" toNode="Trigger" toField="set_boolean"/>
    <ROUTE fromNode="Trigger" fromField="triggerTime" toNode="Clock" toField="startTime"/>

</Scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'real' physics for that.

1. **ball have parameters**

   - acceleration `a(ax,ay,az)` [m/s^2]... this is sum of all forces driving ball divided by its mass
   - velocity `v(vx,vy,vz)` [m/s]... actual speed = integration of acceleration `v += a * dt`
   - position `p(x,y,z)` [m]... actual position = integration of velocity `p += v * dt`
   - radius `r` [m]
   - mass `m` [kg]
   - `dt` [s] ... iteration step (update time)

   init start `a,v` values to `(0,0,0)` and `p` to start position
2. **apply gravity, friction, collision**

   - gravity for example `g(gx=0,gy=-9.81,gz=0)`
   - friction `f2 = -(|v|^2)*c2 * (v/|v|)` ... in gas
   - friction `f3 = -(|v|^3)*c3 * (v/|v|)` ... in liquid

   if position before and after cross collision border reflect velocity * collision coef <=1  by impact normal also you can reflect position if crossing border is not possible.
3. **put it all together in some timer / updating code with `dt` interval**

   ```
   a =g+(f2+f3+(driving force))/m
   v+=a*dt
   p+=v*dt
   test_collisions()
   redraw()
   ```
4. **for manual change of position**

   just set `p(x,y,z)` to new position and also can set `v=(0,0,0)` to stop the ball