# 3D Fireworks Effect in C/C++ using sine or cosine function

Tags: c++, c, animation, trigonometry

I am trying to implement fireworks effect in C. I have a cube with dimensions 10x10x10. A rocket starts from the ground, and when it reaches 8th floor it explodes. Here's the point I cannot do - the explosion. How can I implement this using sine or cosine function?[image]

[image: a busy cat]

so in point(5,0,7) //(x,y,z)// a rocket goes in the air

```
for (j=0; j<9; j++) {
    setpoint(x, y, j);
    delay(100);
    clean();  //clears everything
}
```

Here comes the point to make the explosion. How this can be achieved? It can sparkle in random positions, too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ballistics are closer to parabolas, actually...

Comment: Unless your fireworks have some little thrusters and integrated guidance systems that enable them to follow a sinusoidal path, they're going to follow a parabolic path - at least under the currently enforced laws of physics, and ignoring the effects of wind resistance, etc...

Comment: @Ezio_ I would most likely use particle simulation (gravity + some peak controlled explosion ... just split to all directions after some time or height ...) http://stackoverflow.com/a/20017455/2521214 haven't coded this effect for decades (last time on 386 in asm before that on ZXS) maybe I will for the fun if I have the time later (if yes will post it here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to do this using an upside down parabola instead of sin/cos. At the point of explosion give each particle a random horizontal speed. This speed is constant till the particle hits the ground. You also need to give each particle a random vertical speed. this time, however, you'll add to this speed an amount proportional to `-0.5*g*dt^2` (strictly speaking, this is numerically wrong, but you won't notice unless you're doing scientific analysis). Here, `g` is the acceleration due to gravitation and `dt` is the time step. That's all.

Comment: can you show me example C code for one way parabolic drawing?

Comment: Something like http://www.kirupa.com/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=52027&d=1273492985

Answer (score 5):

Heh I did find some time (done in 1.5 hod) and will for this funny stuff :)

OK first some updates in the LED_cube class to support voxel point output and dimming the rest is the same as for the sphere from your another question ...

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- LED cube class ver: 1.01 ----------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _LED_cube_h
#define _LED_cube_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int _LED_cube_size=32;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class LED_cube
    {
public:
    int n,map[_LED_cube_size][_LED_cube_size][_LED_cube_size];

    LED_cube()              { n=_LED_cube_size; }
    LED_cube(LED_cube& a)   { *this=a; }
    ~LED_cube()             { }
    LED_cube* operator = (const LED_cube *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //LED_cube* operator = (const LED_cube &a) { /*...copy...*/ return this; }
    void cls(int col);                                  // clear cube with col 0x00BBGGRR
    void mul(int mul);                                  // mull all channels by mul and then shr by 8
    void point(int x,int y,int z,int col);              // draws voxel with col 0x00BBGGRR
    void sphere(int x0,int y0,int z0,int r,int col);    // draws sphere surface with col 0x00BBGGRR
    void glDraw();                                      // render cube by OpenGL as 1x1x1 cube at 0,0,0
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void LED_cube::cls(int col)
    {
    int x,y,z;
    for (x=0;x<n;x++)
     for (y=0;y<n;y++)
      for (z=0;z<n;z++)
       map[x][y][z]=col;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void LED_cube::mul(int mul)
    {
    union { BYTE db[4]; int dd; } c;
    int x,y,z,i;
    for (x=0;x<n;x++)
     for (y=0;y<n;y++)
      for (z=0;z<n;z++)
        {
        c.dd=map[x][y][z];
        i=c.db[0]; i=(i*mul)>>8; c.db[0]=i;
        i=c.db[1]; i=(i*mul)>>8; c.db[1]=i;
        i=c.db[2]; i=(i*mul)>>8; c.db[2]=i;
        map[x][y][z]=c.dd;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void LED_cube::point(int x,int y,int z,int col)
    {
    if ((x>=0)&&(x<n))
     if ((y>=0)&&(y<n))
      if ((z>=0)&&(z<n))
       map[x][y][z]=col;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void LED_cube::sphere(int x0,int y0,int z0,int r,int col)
    {
    int x,y,z,xa,ya,za,xb,yb,zb,xr,yr,zr,xx,yy,zz,rr=r*r;
    // bounding box
    xa=x0-r; if (xa<0) xa=0; xb=x0+r; if (xb>n) xb=n;
    ya=y0-r; if (ya<0) ya=0; yb=y0+r; if (yb>n) yb=n;
    za=z0-r; if (za<0) za=0; zb=z0+r; if (zb>n) zb=n;
    // project xy plane
    for (x=xa,xr=x-x0,xx=xr*xr;x<xb;x++,xr++,xx=xr*xr)
     for (y=ya,yr=y-y0,yy=yr*yr;y<yb;y++,yr++,yy=yr*yr)
        {
        zz=rr-xx-yy; if (zz<0) continue; zr=sqrt(zz);
        z=z0-zr; if ((z>0)&&(z<n)) map[x][y][z]=col;
        z=z0+zr; if ((z>0)&&(z<n)) map[x][y][z]=col;
        }
    // project xz plane
    for (x=xa,xr=x-x0,xx=xr*xr;x<xb;x++,xr++,xx=xr*xr)
     for (z=za,zr=z-z0,zz=zr*zr;z<zb;z++,zr++,zz=zr*zr)
        {
        yy=rr-xx-zz; if (yy<0) continue; yr=sqrt(yy);
        y=y0-yr; if ((y>0)&&(y<n)) map[x][y][z]=col;
        y=y0+yr; if ((y>0)&&(y<n)) map[x][y][z]=col;
        }
    // project yz plane
    for (y=ya,yr=y-y0,yy=yr*yr;y<yb;y++,yr++,yy=yr*yr)
     for (z=za,zr=z-z0,zz=zr*zr;z<zb;z++,zr++,zz=zr*zr)
        {
        xx=rr-zz-yy; if (xx<0) continue; xr=sqrt(xx);
        x=x0-xr; if ((x>0)&&(x<n)) map[x][y][z]=col;
        x=x0+xr; if ((x>0)&&(x<n)) map[x][y][z]=col;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void LED_cube::glDraw()
    {
    #ifdef __gl_h_
    int x,y,z;
    float p[3],dp=1.0/float(n-1);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ONE);

    glPointSize(2.0);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);

    for (p[0]=-0.5,x=0;x<n;x++,p[0]+=dp)
     for (p[1]=-0.5,y=0;y<n;y++,p[1]+=dp)
      for (p[2]=-0.5,z=0;z<n;z++,p[2]+=dp)
        {
        glColor4ubv((BYTE*)(&map[x][y][z]));
        glVertex3fv(p);
        }
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glPointSize(1.0);
    #endif
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- the important stuff are:
- `void mul(int mul);` - used for dimming out the whole voxel map
- `void point(int x,int y,int z,int col);` - used to set collor of single voxel

**Now the particles**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class particle
    {
public:
    double  x, y, z;    // position
    double vx,vy,vz;    // velocity
    double ax,ay,az;    // acceleration driving force/m after update is reseted
    double i;           // intensity
    particle()
        {
         x=0.0;  y=0.0;  z=0.0;
        vx=0.0; vy=0.0; vz=0.0;
        ax=0.0; ay=0.0; az=0.0;
        i=0.0;
        };
    particle(particle& a){ *this=a; };
    ~particle(){};
    particle* operator = (const particle *a) { *this=*a; return this; };
//  particle* operator = (const particle &a) { ...copy... return this; };

    void update(double dt)
        {
        double c0,c;
        // gravity
        ay-=9.81;
        // friction in gass
        c=0.001;
        if (vx>0.0) c0=-c; else c0=+c; ax+=vx*vx*c0;
        if (vy>0.0) c0=-c; else c0=+c; ay+=vy*vy*c0;
        if (vz>0.0) c0=-c; else c0=+c; az+=vz*vz*c0;
        // friction in liquid
        c=0.0;
        ax-=vx*vx*vx*c;
        ay-=vy*vy*vy*c;
        az-=vz*vz*vz*c;
        // D'ALembert
        vx+=ax*dt;
        vy+=ay*dt;
        vz+=az*dt;
         x+=vx*dt;
         y+=vy*dt;
         z+=vz*dt;
        // reset acceleration
        ax=0.0; ay=0.0; az=0.0;
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
List<particle> particles; // use any list/array you have at your disposal you need just function add and delete item
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this is how to draw the scene:

```
cube.mul(200);          // dimm the voxel map insted of clearing it  (intensity*=200/256)
for (int i=0;i<particles.num;i++)
    {
    particle *p=&particles[i];
    int j=double(255.0*p->i);
    if (j<0) j=0;
    if (j>255) j=255;
    cube.point(p->x,p->y,p->z,0x00010101*j);
    }
cube.glDraw();
```

This is how to update simulation in some timer (double dt=timer interval in seconds !!!)

```
double i0=1.0; // intensity at shoot start
double i1=0.9*i0; // intensity after explosion
double v0=0.6*double(_LED_cube_size); // shoot start speed
double v1=0.5*v0,v1h=0.5*v1; // explosion speed
if (particles.num==0) // shoot new particle if none in list
    {
    particle p;
    p.x=_LED_cube_size>>1;
    p.y=0.0;
    p.z=_LED_cube_size>>1;
    p.vy=v0;
    p.i=i0;
    particles.add(p);
    }
for (int i=0;i<particles.num;i++) // update all particles in list
    {
    particle *p=&particles[i];
    p->update(dt);
    if (fabs(p->i-i0)<1e-6)     // intensity detect state before explosion
        {
        if (p->vy<=0.0)         // explode near/after peak reached
            {
            particle q;
            q.x=p->x;               // copy position
            q.y=p->y;
            q.z=p->z;
            q.i=i1;                 // new intensity
            particles.del(i);       // remove old particle
            i--;
            for (int j=0;j<50;j++)  // add new random particles
                {
                q.vx=v1*Random()-v1h;
                q.vy=v1*Random()-v1h;
                q.vz=v1*Random()-v1h;
                particles.add(q)-v1h;
                }
            continue;               // avoid usage of p pointer after delete
            }
        }
    else{                       // after explosion
        p->i*=0.95;             // dimm intensity
        }
    if ((p->y<0.0)||(p->i<0.01))// remove particles below the ground or too dimmed out
        {
        particles.del(i);
        i--;
        continue;               // avoid usage of p pointer after delete
        }
    }
```

This is how it looks

[image: particles]

Sorry for the banner but I do not have anything solid for gif conversion and this site will not accept wmv ... You have to play with constants to match desired output on your LED cube size constants to play with:

1. whole cube map dimm rate (cube.mul(200)) currently (200/256) per frame
2. speeds,intensities `v0,v1,i0,i1`
3. number of new particles after explosion currently 50
4. particle intensity dimm rate after explosion currently 0.95

**[Notes]**

`List<>` is just template for dynamic array can use anything from `std::` or own array ...

Do not forget to set `dt` constant to time elapsed between updates. Hope I did not forget to copy something. Hope it helps