# I need help writing a program that simulates a circle going down a hill with a velocity vector

Tags: physics

I need to write a program that simulates a ring going down a hill showing the velocity vector. Or at least a simulation of a circle rotating with a velocity vector. It doesn't necessarily need to be going down a hill. This is what I have so far. Thank you so much to anyone that can help.

```
'''
cylinderhill.py
'''
from visual import *
from math import *

inclinedPlane = box(pos = vector(1, 0, 0), size = (2, 0.2, 0.2), color = color.blue)
cir = ring(pos=(5,0,0), axis=(5,0,0), radius = (.05), thickness = (.01), color = color.red)
cir.vel = vector(1,1)
```

Comment: "This is what I have so far". I.e. nothing much. What are you thinking needs doing next?

Comment: You seem to want an animated image of the rotating ring. I suggest you start with an animated image of a moving, non-rotating ring. Once that's working perfectly, you can look into making it rotate.

Answer (score 0):

1. **add needed variables for you object (ring)**

   you need: `position,velocity,acceleration,radiuses` and set them at start to start position/state (speeds to zero ...).
2. **create engine App able of redrawing the scene**

   all objects (ring,surface ...) and update/redraw on some timer
3. **add physical simulation**

   compute actual acceleration `acc` (gravity,surface/collision normal interaction,frictions,actuators,...). Then update velocity `vel`,position `pos` according to **Newtonian/D'Alembert** equations

   ```
   vel+=acc*dt;
   pos+=vel*dt;
   ```

   do this in each ontimer call before redraw. The `dt` is the timer interval ...
4. **some tips**

   add `if (|vel|<1e-6) vel={0,0,...,0};` before `pos` update to avoid floating accuracy problems. The `acc,vel,pos` are vectors (for 2D simulation use 2D vectors). Use float or double variables.
5. **rotation**

   if you have no drift (full grip) then angular speed is:

   ```
   omg=|vel|/R;
   ```

   where `R` is ring's outer radius. If you have a drift then you have to compute angular acceleration `eps` first from external and internal forces and then compute:

   ```
   omg+=eps*dt;
   ```

   the rest is similar to position computation... angular position:

   ```
   ang+=omg*dt;
   ```

See some related **Q/A**:

- [bouncing ball simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20017455/2521214)
- [how to build own physic simulation/editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26584358/2521214)