# Figure out what keys a player is pressing based on relative velocity and angle

Tags: c#, math, rotation, geometry, 2d

I have two pieces of information: a 2D-vector representing velocity relative to a grid and an angle (180 to negative 180 degrees) representing the player's view-angle also relative to that grid, and I am from that trying to figure out what keys (W, A, S, D) the player is pressing with this information.

The thing that is giving me troubles are the fact that the player moves in respect to the view-angle. So if the player is looking 35 degrees relative to our grid and pressing forward (W), the player will move forward 35 degrees which gives the velocity a mixture of forward and right (D).
Something to note is that the maximum speed that a player gets from pressing a key is 250 units/s in that direction. But the vector gets taken into some calculation with the view angle which yields the final movement-speed, and this is why I'm asking this question.

I basically want to cancel out the angle's impact on the velocity vector.

For this, I tried using a Rotation-matrix solution using the following formula:

```
x' =  x*cos(angle) - y*sin(angle)
y' =  x*sin(angle) + y*cos(angle)
```

but this didn't give me good results, it seems like they are kind of the same as the original velocity vector.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? Shouldn't I just be able to calculate these values using a rotation matrix?

Comment: you cant just have the velocity - you also need the acceleration (for state changes)

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah Wait, why? What do you mean by state changes?

Comment: sorry direction changes, so key state changes

Comment: Okay, but where should I incorporate acceleration? (Its not a problem getting them, I just don't understand what to do with an acceleration vector in this context)

Comment: Say if you are moving in some direction at some speed, e.g. left. Then a trivial solution would be the A key. But you could also be decelerating, i.e. pressing D, or at constant speed - no keys pressed (assuming no friction). So if you don't taking into account the acceleration you have a non-deterministic outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to know more about the physics  like:

1. **is there inertia present (movement and / or rotation)?**

   speed/direction changes immediately or slowly in time?
2. **Keys drive acceleration or velocity?**

   speed/direction changes immediately or continuously in time with key press/hold/release?
3. **Are there any frictions?**

   object stops if not pressed any key after time or immediately or never?

**Now how to attack this**

First see

- [Newton - D'Alembert physics for non relativistic speeds dictates this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19764828/2521214)
- [Newton - D'Alembert physics and force fields+frictions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20017455/2521214)

which are usually used for update of object position/direction/speed. From that is the rest easy ...

For example lets assume keys drive acceleration,inertia is present,no frictions, and you got only position `p`, orientation `alpha` and speed `v` info in 2D.

1. **so you need to have some update routine like timer with some `dt` interval**
2. **remove frictions from `v,omega` if present**

   just multiply the speed by inverse of friction to obtain original speed... **This must be done before acceleration computation !!!**
3. **compute acceleration `a,epsilon` from speed `v,omega`**

   That is easy it is just derivation by time:

   ```
         a(t)=(    v(t)-    v(t-dt))/dt
   epsilon(t)=(omega(t)-omega(t-dt))/dt
   ```

   Where `t` is actual time and `dt` is time step of your update routine. The `a(t)` means actual value and `a(t-dt)` means previous value from last update.  So if you got only position info instead you can do similarly:

   ```
   v(t)=(p(t)-p(t-dt))/dt
   a(t)=(v(t)-v(t-dt))/dt
     omega(t)=(alpha(t)-alpha(t-dt))/dt
   epsilon(t)=(omega(t)-omega(t-dt))/dt
   ```

   For angular delta `(alpha(t)-alpha(t-dt))` you should ensure that the abs result is always smaller or equal then 180 degrees if not add/remove 360 degrees until it is.
4. **remove forcefields from `a` if present**

   for example if you got gravity present ... etc subbstract it. The only thing that should be left in the accelerations is the key strokes driven acceleration bumps
5. **decode keystrokes**

   That is easy for example if you movement schema is like turn left/right and move forward/backward  then just extract the info (+/- your coordinate system corrections). The turning is directly visible in angular acceleration `epsilon`:

   ```
   if (epsilon>+ang_treshold) `D` is pressed; // turn left
   if (epsilon<-ang_treshold) `A` is pressed; // turn right
   ```

   Now you just convert your movement acceleration `a` into orientation so it became local to you object by dot product with LCS (local coordinate system) axises:

   ```
   lcs_a.x=(a.x*cos(alpha      ))+(a.y*sin(alpha      ));
   lcs_a.y=(a.x*cos(alpha-90deg))+(a.y*sin(alpha-90deg));
   ```

   And similarly investigate the bumps...

   ```
   if (lcs_a.y>+mov_treshold) `W` is pressed; // move forward
   if (lcs_a.y<-mov_treshold) `S` is pressed; // move backward
   if (lcs_a.x>+mov_treshold) `E` is pressed; // move right 
   if (lcs_a.x<-mov_treshold) `Q` is pressed; // move left
   ```

   If your simulation is driven by speed then you will just investigate speed instead of acceleration in the same manner. The tresholds should be smaller but close to the actual key strokes acceleration bumps to avoid miss registration of some forgotten friction or what ever ... for start you can use `0` and if wrongly detected keystrokes then increase it a bit ... Safest way would be draw a graph of `a` as a function of time and read the values from it while key is active ... so you actually see the right value immediately instead of guessing ...

Comment: It did take a while to wrap my head around this, I must admit. But your answer gave me all the information I needed to implement this. Thank you =)