# How to calculate rocket?

Tags: javascript, math, calculation

So I got a **3d system** and some coordinates:

- Start coordinates (x, y, z) of a rocket (on the ground)
- Target coordinates (x, y, z) of the rockets target (also on the ground)

---

I got some initialize values like:

- maximum_velocityZ = 0.5
- maximum_resVelocityXY = 0.3
- gravity factor = 9.81

---

How can I calculate the flight velocitys `(velocityX, velocityY and velocityZ)` for every update frame?

```js
let maximum_velocityZ = 0.5
let maximum_resVelocityXY = 0.3
let gravity_factor = 9.81

let rocketPosition = {
  x: 3,
  y: 0,
  z: 2
}
let rocketTarget = {
  x: 7,
  y: 5,
  z: 8
}
let rocketVelocity = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  z: 0
}
let update = function() {
  rocketPosition.x += rocketVelocity.x
  rocketPosition.y += rocketVelocity.y
  rocketPosition.z += rocketVelocity.z

  let distanceX = (rocketTarget.x - rocketPosition.x)
  let distanceY = (rocketTarget.y - rocketPosition.y)
  let distanceZ = (rocketTarget.z - rocketPosition.z)

  let factorXY = Math.abs(distanceX / distanceY)
  rocketVelocity.x = maximum_resVelocityXY / Math.sqrt((1 / factorXY ** 2) + 1) * (distanceX > 0 ? 1 : -1)
  rocketVelocity.y = maximum_resVelocityXY / Math.sqrt((factorXY ** 2) + 1) * (distanceY > 0 ? 1 : -1)
  rocketVelocity.z = maximum_velocityZ * distanceZ;
  rocketVelocity.z /= gravity_factor;

  console.log("x:", Math.round(rocketPosition.x), "y:", Math.round(rocketPosition.y), "z:", Math.round(rocketPosition.z))
}

setInterval(update, 300)
```

This code is what I've developed so far. I'm sure I'm on the right track. X and Y seem to be more or less right. Only the Velocity Z can't be calculated the way I tried. **In 3D space the trajectory doesn't really look realistic. So by "not really" I mean "not realistic at all"...**

I would be happy for help. Thanks and a happy new year - matching to the rocket - of course!

Comment: Hint: get it working for an xy plane (e.g. as shown in [Projectile motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion)). Once that is working, you can rotate the coordinate system instead of trying to have three dimensions in the motion calculations.

Comment: @jonas00 I finish the C++ example as promised ... I updated my answer with new code and preview animation ... luckily I was able to avoid any trigonometry horibleness nor used matrices just simple vectors ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what is you coordinate system

- plane
- sphere
- ellipsoid like **WGS84**

My guess is your ground is planar (induced from your constants however your positions suggest something else)... so I will stick with that for now... You got 2 problems:

1. **Newton/D'Alembert physics**

   Yours is weird as you got no `dt` multiplication so it works only if your update is 1 Hz. take a look at this:

   - [Can't flip direction of ball without messing up gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53637567/2521214)

   you do not need speed limiter as air friction will do it for you and you should drive with accelerations ... or Force if you want to account for mass changes too.

   However as you are working with ground/ground then I assume atmospheric flight instead of Newtonian so in such case you need to handle the heading control not by acceleration but by turning the integrated velocity. The main thruster should still be handled as acceleration.

   The collisions are not necessary in your case (unless your ground is not planar or have obstacles along the way).
2. **Rocket guiding system**

   I suggest to use 3 state (Markovov model) rocket control.

   1. launch

      Rise the rocket to safe altitude first to avoid obstacles, conserve fuel and maximize speed
   2. cruise

      Travel to the target area (while still keep its altitude). Simply compute heading projected on the ground plane and apply correction to the heading of the rocket to match it (still going parallel to ground).
   3. hit

      Hit the target while descending. Almost the same as **#2** but this time you need to change altitude too...

   On top of these you can add strategies to avoid detection/destruction or obstacles etc ... You can also make a fake approach from different heading to keep the launch position hidden ...

**Here a simple C++ example of this approach:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void  vector_one(double *c,double *a)
    {
    double l=sqrt((a[0]*a[0])+(a[1]*a[1])+(a[2]*a[2]));
    if (l>1e-10) l=1.0/l; else l=0.0;
    c[0]=a[0]*l;
    c[1]=a[1]*l;
    c[2]=a[2]*l;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Z=0 plane is ground, Z+ is up
const double g=9.81;                // [m/s^2] Earth's gravity
const double acc0=20.0;             // [m/s^2] rocket main thruster acceleration
const double kv2 =0.002;            // [-] rocket air friction coeff (speed limiter)
const double alt0=50.0;             // [m] rocket safe altitude
const double dis0=100.0;            // [m] rocket safe distance to target
const double dis1= 10.0;            // [m] rocket explosion distance to target
const double dang0=375.0*M_PI/180.0;// [rad/s] rocket turn speed per yaw/roll/pitch
// Rocket
double dst[3]={+90.0,-50.0,0.0};    // [m] target position
double pos[3]={-100.0,200.0,0.0};   // [m] rocket position
double vel[3]={  0.0,  0.0,0.0};    // [m/s] rocket velocity
double acc[3]={  0.0,  0.0,0.0};    // [m/s^2] rocket acceleration
enum{
    _state_none=0,
    _state_launch,                  // rise to alt0
    _state_cruise,                  // get near target but maintain alt0
    _state_hit,                     // descend and hit
    };
int state=_state_launch;
void update(double dt)              // update rocket after dt [sec] has passed
    {
    int i;
    double v,a,hdg[3],tar[3];
    // guiding system
    if (state==_state_none)
        {
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) vel[i]=0.0;
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) acc[i]=0.0;
        return;
        }
    if (state==_state_launch)
        {
        // init heading to Up
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) hdg[i]=0.0; hdg[2]=1.0;
        if (pos[2]>=alt0) state=_state_cruise;
        }
    v=sqrt((vel[0]*vel[0])+(vel[1]*vel[1])+(vel[2]*vel[2]));// |vel|
    if ((state==_state_cruise)||(state==_state_hit))
        {
        vector_one(hdg,vel);                        // heading
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) tar[i]=dst[i]-pos[i];     // to target
        a=sqrt((tar[0]*tar[0])+(tar[1]*tar[1])+(tar[2]*tar[2])); // distance to target
        if (state==_state_cruise)
            {
            tar[2]=0;                               // no altitude change
            if (a<=dis0) state=_state_hit;
            }
        else{
            if (a<=dis1) state=_state_none;         // here you shoul add exlosion code
            }
        vector_one(tar,tar);
        // a = angle between hdg and tar [rad]
        for (a=0.0,i=0;i<3;i++) a+=hdg[i]*tar[i];
        a=fabs(acos(a));
        // approximate turn up to dang0
        if (a>1e-10) a=dt*dang0/a; else a=0.0;
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) hdg[i]=hdg[i]+a*(tar[i]-hdg[i]);
        vector_one(hdg,hdg);                        // new heading
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) vel[i]=v*hdg[i];          // new vel
        }
    // physics
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) acc[i] =-kv2*vel[i]*v;        // air friction (k*|vel|^2)
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) acc[i]+=hdg[i]*acc0;          // rocket thrust
    acc[2]-=g;                                      // gravity
    // Newton/D'Alembert simulation
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) vel[i]+=acc[i]*dt;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) pos[i]+=vel[i]*dt;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You might need to tweak the constants a bit to match your sizes and game needs. As you can see you can customize the rocket quite  a lot which is ideal for game (tech upgrades).

The physics is straight forward Newton/D'Alembert (apart the `vel` turning due to wings) and the guiding system works as described above. In first state the rocket just rise to `alt0` then it try to turn towards target with `dang0` turn speed while maintaining altitude and when closer than `dis0` it start also descending. If closer than `dis1` the rocket should explode ...

Here preview (top view):

[image: rocket flight]

The white line is line from ground to verify the altitude of rocket ... Rocket is Blue and target is Red.

The turning math is like this:

[image: turn math]

so I just scaled `tar-hdg` to approximately match `dang0*dt` and add that to original `hdg`. now the new heading is turned towards target by up to `dang0*dt` so just  I  normalize it back to unit size and recompute velocity to this new direction (as wings are turning velocity instead of accelerating)

**Beware of the units**

All the units used must be compatible I am using **SI**. Your `9.81` constant suggest the same but your position and target values makes no sense if in meters ... Why shoot rocket if target is just few meters away? Also the values suggest your coordinates are either not cartessian or ground is not planar/flat. Also the values suggest integers hope you have floats/doubles instead...

Answer (score 0):

The trajectory will be a parabola. The basic equations of which are explained quite well here: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-physics/chapter/projectile-motion/

The 3D problem (x, y, z) can be easily be transformed to a 2D (single plane) problem (horizontal, vertical), for the equations then back to 3D for the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have looked at your source but must honestly say that I have problems applying the formulas appropriately to my problem - not only because of the 3d-2d problem. As I said - thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Rocket is not a projectile ... the trajectory is different ... and also rockets usually track the target ... projectiles do not change trajectory that much ... not to mention many projectiles are going in helix trajectories (even arrows shoot from bow are doing it sometimes) ... so the link is just for a very special set of cases. With integration you do not need any goniometrics  and the equation is quite  simple in any dimensionality... so converting into 2D and than back to 3D is not very practical for game (unless solved by human on paper)