# How can I scale a 2D rotation vector without trig functions?

Tags: geometry, 2d, trigonometry

I have a normalized 2D vector that I am using to rotate other 2D vectors. In one instance it indicates "spin" (or "angular momentum") and is used to rotate the "orientation" of a simple polygon. My vector class contains this method:

```
rotateByXY(x, y) {
  let rotX = x * this.x - y * this.y;
  let rotY = y * this.x + x * this.y;
  this.x = rotX;
  this.y = rotY;
}
```

So far, this is all efficient and uses no trig whatsoever.

However, I want the "spin" to decay over time. This means that the angle of the spin should tend towards zero. And here I'm at a loss as to how to do this without expensive trig calls like this:

```
let angle = Math.atan2(spin.y, spin.x);
angle *= SPIN_DECAY;
spin = new Vector2D(Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle));
```

Is there a better/faster way to accomplish this?

Comment: Simple formulas exist only for `SPIN_DECAY = 1/2` (and for arithmetic progression `an[i] = an0 - i*da`). Otherwise it would better to store `angle` to avoid `atan2`. If you apply the same rotation to multiple points, single evaluation of sin/cos per step is not so bad.

Comment: what about this: [How to calculate rocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53986426/2521214) see the rotation math at the end...  beware it works only for rotations up to `90deg` and the rotation is not linear but not too far from it either and works for any dimensionality...the dimming is done simply by decreasing the `dang0` or by `dang0*=0.95` each iteration etc ... you do not need the `acos` for  computing `a` as you already know how much your original rotation rotates ...

Comment: Another idea: what about approximating your trigonometric functions with their Taylor expansions?

Comment: @DominikMokriš, that sounds intriguing. Can you say more and/or provide details? Not quite sure how to implement that.

BTW, I did consider something like this lookup:

int iX = int((spin.x + 1) * 100);
int iY = int((spin.y + 1) * 100);

spin = DecayLookupX[iX][iY];
Where DecayLookup is a 200 x 200 array of pre-calculated vectors (could be tuned). A bit rough, but would work for a constant decay.

Answer (score 2):

If it's really the trigonometric functions what is slowing down your computation, you might try to approximate them with their [Taylor expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

For `x` close to zero the [following identities hold](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html):

```
cos(x) = 1 - (x^2)/2! + (x^4)/4! - (x^6)/6! + ...
sin(x) = x - (x^3)/3! + (x^5)/5! - (x^7)/7! + ...
atan(x) = x - (x^3)/3 + (x^5)/5 - (x^7)/7 + ...
```

Based on the degree of accuracy you need for your application you can trim the series. For instance,

```
cos(x) = 1 - (x^2)/2
```

with an error of the order of `x^3` (actually, `x^4`, as the term with `x^3` is zero anyway).

However, I don't think that this is going to solve your problem: the actual implementation of `atan` is likely to be already using the same trick, written by someone with lots of experience of speeding these things up. So this is not really a proper answer but I hope it could still be useful.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for that explanation. This might be worth looking into. Although since my decay should be constant I think I might be able to get away with a pre-calculated lookup table. Appreciate it though!