# How to calculate reflection angle of a ball colliding with a wall

Tags: javascript, math, game-physics

I have a ball and I'm moving it toward an angle like this:

```
ball.x += ball.speed * Math.sin(ball.angle)
ball.y += ball.speed * -Math.cos(ball.angle)
```

How can I calculate the reflection angle when the ball collides with a wall?(horizontal or vertical)

Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sllark/m43ontkf/9/)

Comment: `135` not `180` ... i.e in this case, it's (180 - 45) ... `180 * (Math.PI / 180) - ball.angle;`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1cuj0z3q/

Comment: see [Can't flip direction of ball without messing up gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53637567/2521214)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any wall with normal vector `e_n` a ball with initial velocity vector `v_i` has the velocity vector `v_f` after reflection with

`v_f = v_i - 2 dot( v_i, e_n) e_n`,

where `dot` is the vector dot-product.

Explanation:
 The projection of `v_i` on `e_n` is `dot( v_i, e_n )`. This is the velocity towards the wall and this is the part that gets reversed upon reflection. The component `p = dot( v_i, e_n )` results in a vector `p e_n`. The remaining component can be calculated via a cross product or simply `v_s = v_i - p e_n`. The final velocity is the non altered component plus the reversed projected component, i.e. `v_s - p e_n = v_i - 2 p e_n =  v_i - 2 dot( v_i, e_n) e_n`

Comment: This is assuming a non-rotating ball. In reality friction and refection at oblique angles would result in a change of rotation as well (This changes distribution of internal energies and effects velocity as well etc. etc.) Hence the edges on a pool table which are placed in a height such that spin is also reflected properly.